# error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 1: did not find expected ',' or '}'

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-helm, elk

New here, just wanted some help here as to what is causing the following error when I try deploying a cluster:

```
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: YAML parse error on kube-prometheus-stack/charts/elasticsearch/templates/elastic-certificate-secrets.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 1: did not find expected ',' or '}'
```

This is my current elastic-certificate-secrets.yaml file:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
    name: elastic-certificate-p12
type: Opaque
data:
    server.p12: {{ (.Files.Get “server.p12”) | b64enc  }}
```

Comment: How are you trying to use this file?  The `{{ ... }}` templating looks like it should go with a Helm chart, and it would cause a parse error if you used it with `kubectl apply`.  If it is in a Helm chart, sometimes running `helm template --debug` over the chart can help you find where a parsing problem in its output might be.

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to add `---` when you only have a single resource in your file. You can try removing it and it should work.

This is typically used to separate multiple resources in a file and usually comes "between" two resource definitions.

Comment: why would you think `---` is a problem? just wondering?

Comment: I would just guess, that `---` would be used as a token to split the contents of the YAML into multiple objects. If there is just 1 object, the "first" element of the split will be an empty object since there's nothing before the `---`. Therefore, the parser will complain that it was expecting a "{" character and instead found nothing.

Comment: well I ran the deployment with that --- and it seemed to work so not sure if that's the fix

Comment: I've known this to fail and it is a very flakey logic. It's best to avoid having this complication when it is obviously not needed. It serves no purpose to start a file with  `---` when it only has 1 object.

Comment: Amazing! This should be a bug, as this fixed the issue. `---` in a yaml file  with just one document doesn't seems wrong. IMO

Comment: I agree. It's a really annoying bug :)

Comment: This is something that should be fixed then, because I feel that even though it doesn't matter, it's weird logic for sure as said by @zer0

Comment: Perhaps an issue in `kubectl` community can be created for this since I think this is specific to this binary.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is *likely* due to the use of Windows-style double quotes. (Of course, if you are not operating on a windows environment) Change:

```
 “server.p12”
```

to

```
"server.p12"
```

Comment: Cool, I happen to use MacOS so yeah this is defo helpful. Let me try this out. Cheers!